# Pushing data with new key and adding calculation with previous array and new array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

https://jsfiddle.net/2uhs8o9m/

Expecting result would be

```
myData: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Russell',
    country: 'Windes',
    amount: 7,
    myaddedResult: [
      {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Watson',
          country: 'Australia',
          amount: 9,
          sumOfAmount: 16
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Marcus',
          country: 'England',
          amount: 10,
          sumOfAmount: 17
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Smith',
    country: 'USA',
    amount: 8,
    myaddedResult: [
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Watson',
            country: 'Australia',
            amount: 9,
            sumOfAmount: 17
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Marcus',
            country: 'England',
            amount: 10,
            sumOfAmount: 18
          }
      ]
  }
],
```

I tried it in my jsfiddle into myData copy ownerData in it with new field and new field will have the sum of myData's amount and ownerData's amount currently it will pushing last element value only.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to compute array value and add extra file with sum of amount javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71662529/how-to-compute-array-value-and-add-extra-file-with-sum-of-amount-javascript)

Comment: No, you actually have to fix what's wrong with your question, you don't get to just ask it again.

Comment: What is unclear just check the jsfiddle where there are two array object where ownerData array to be pushed into myData with new field that can say sumAmount of myData and ownerData simple

Comment: I said nothing about unclear. As I said on the duplicate question, read [ask]. All code relevant to the question must be on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's your solution.

```js
const userData = {
    myData: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Russell',
            country: 'Windes',
            amount: 7,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Smith',
            country: 'USA',
            amount: 8,
        },
    ],
    ownerData: [
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Watson',
            country: 'Australia',
            amount: 9,
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Marcus',
            country: 'England',
            amount: 10,
        },
    ],
};

const mapped = userData.myData.map((user) => {
    return {
        ...user,
        myAddedResult: userData.ownerData.map((owner) => {
            return {
                ...owner,
                sumOfAmount: owner.amount + user.amount,
            };
        }),
    };
});

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Please refer to sfiddle where there are two array object where ownerData array to be pushed into myData with new field that can say sumAmount of myData and ownerData simple

Comment: Where the heck does amount come from? In your JSFiddle you have no references to `amount` anywhere

Comment: updated the jsfiddle please take a look i guess very close https://jsfiddle.net/2uhs8o9m/

Comment: @John Check updated answer.